# VBA Excel Workbooks Object Variable

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to set two workbook variables - here are the first four lines of my code:

```
Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim wb2 As Workbook

Set wb1 = Workbooks("C:\Users\ShaneM\Documents\File1.xlsx")
Set wb2 = Workbooks("C:\Users\ShaneM\Documents\Computer Languages\VBA\File2.xlsm")
```

The error I am getting on line 3 is:

```
Runtime error 9 - Subscript Out Of Range
```

The files definitely exist in these locations. Obviously much learning to be done. What am I doing wrong, please?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you trying to open the workbooks? If yes, I think you must use the open method: [https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff194819.aspx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff194819.aspx) I have never seen the index notation for opening workbooks, but to select a sheet in a workbook already opened. Try finding code snippets by googling, there are tons of snippets out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841074.aspx, the `Workbooks` collection contains only the **currently opened** workbooks. The error simply tells you, that the requested workbook is not opened at the moment.

You have to use the method [Workbooks.Open](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194819.aspx):

```
Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\ShaneM\Documents\File1.xlsx")
```

When the Workbook is already opened, you can then use the property [Workbooks.Item](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff196016.aspx) to get the object (note that you can omit `.Item`, as it is the default property of the `Workbooks` collection).

```
Set wb1 = Workbooks("File1.xlsx")
```

Also note that the names of opened workbooks must be unique within the same application. I.e. the following will **not** work:

```
Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Folder1\File.xlsx")
Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Folder2\File.xlsx")
```

Comment: Vielen Dank Conrad. I can see my error now - I was trying to assign a variable before the Workbook was open. Your line does the two operations in one step. I hadn't seen this construction before! Many thanks for your answer.

Comment: Please also have a look at Matteo's answer which explains how to open a workbook in a seperate hidden instance of Excel. This has several advantages, such as the opened workbooks not being visible to the user. I suggest using it if you were to programmatically read/write data from/to the mentioned workbooks, for instance.

Answer (score 2):

The `.Workbooks()` is a collection of workbook objects opened in the current `Application` object (which you don't write in your code, but it's called by default).

The collection `.Workbooks()` goes `out of range` because the workbook is not currently open in your `Application`; if you want to use your workbook, in fact, what you need to do is opening it into the current Excel `Application` instance:

```
Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open("C:\...")
```

This will though cause the workbook to show up, because you're opening in your current application, and unfortunately is not possible to open it in `Visible=False` mode. However, you might want to use a new Excel instance set to `Visible = False`, so you will be able to read the content without actually displaying it. Which means, in code:

```
Set excObj = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
excObj.Visible = False
Set wb1 = excObj.Workbooks.Open("C:\...")
```

Please note that I'm specifying to open the workbook with `excObj`, which is not the current `Application` but another object of the same type that is intentionally set to `Visible = False`.

Comment: Thank you Matteo. Presumably then I can open File1 in the non-visible instance of Excel, where 'excObj.Visible = False', and copy values over from this into File 1 which is in the visible instance, where 'excObj.Visible = True'? Do I have to implicitly set this second variable myself? I would guess not as I'm sure there has to be at least one visible Excel instance. Thanks!